# UITests: How to test if label contains some text after changes?

Tags: swift, ios9, xcode-ui-testing

[image]

How do I write a `UITest` to check whether my label (currently with the text: `2`) has changed its value to `3` or not after I tap my **plus button**.

Answer (score 2):

```
let app = XCUIApplication()    
let textPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "label = %@", "3")
expectationForPredicate(textPredicate, evaluatedWithObject: app.staticTexts["numberOfItemsLabel"], handler: nil)
app.buttons["increaseNumberOfItemsButton"].tap()
```

Comment: Please consider adding some detail to your answer.